# combining n number of files with cat command

Tags: shell-script, cat

I have n number of files, I have stored filenames in a list and I want to combine them. I am doing this manually, 
i.e. If n=3

```
cat ${filename[1]} ${filename[2]} ${filename[3]} > newfile
```

If the content of the file is as follows:

```
filename[1]:
  line1
  line2

filename[2]:
  line3
  line4

filename[3]:
  line5
  line6
```

I want the newfile to have

```
newfile:
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

How can I do this automatically, i.e. for any number of files "n", I want to combine them sequentially as I am doing here for three files manually

Comment: The files have the same prefix? Are they sequential? Do they follow a specific sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use '@', for example:

```
$ files=( /tmp/a "/tmp/a file from windows" /tmp/myfile )
$ cat "${files[@]}" > newfile
```

The '@' expands the entire contents of the array. It is similar to `*`except it will treat each element individuals whereas `*` will combine all elements as one.

Comment: This works, thanks!. what does the @ command do? it combines calls all the elements of the list sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do cat inputfile$i>>outputfile; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with `zsh`.

```
% echo blah > a; echo asdf > b; echo harfjr > c;
% filenames=(a b c d e)
% print -l $filenames[1,3]
a
b
c
% cat $filenames[1,3]
blah
asdf
harfjr
% cat $filenames[1,3] > anewfile
% cat anewfile
blah
asdf
harfjr
% somenum=2   
% print -l $filenames[1,$somenum]
a
b
%
```

If the shell is actually `bash` or `ksh` uhhh dunno.

Comment: would this combine the files?

Comment: I want to combine the context of the file.
e.g.
file1.txt has
line1
line2

file2.txt has
line3
line4

I want to combine them into a new file that has
line1
line2
line3
line4

Comment: So pass the filenames to `cat` instead of `print -l`.

Comment: thats what I am currently doing. Is there a way to automate this. Please see the edit in the question, may be that would make it clear

Comment: This is not working for me. I have file names as variables in a list, the above code gives me error. I am accessing them as ${filenames[1,3]} but doing this only copies the content of 2nd file into the new file